# how to detect the current user's permissions for a web part

Tags: 2010, development, web-part, visual-studio

In SharePoint 2010, I have custom Web Parts. In the Web Part Gallery, I grant read permissions to certain users to let them add these web parts to a page. Within CreateChildControls, how can I detect if the current user is able to read the current web part?

Basically, I am looking for the equivalent of the DoesUserHavePermissions method (from SPList) for the current web part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in your `CreateChildControls` method:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{   
    using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://sitecollectionurl"))
    {
         using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
         {
            // Get the current user.
            SPUser currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
            // Get the list.
            SPList spList = spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");
            // Variable to determine permission.

            bool userPermission = spList.DoesUserHavePermissions(currentUser, SPBasePermissions.AddListItems);
            if (userPermission)
            {
                  // Perform operation here.
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is the DoesUserHavePermissions method for interrogating a LIST. I mentioned that. I am looking for something similar to interrogate the current WEB PART.

Comment: In the line trygetlist, use spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Web Part Gallery");